# PhoneGap/Cordova Image Hyperlink Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to get an image inside a popup to hyperlink to the full size image stored on my company's server. Simple href doesn't work, and I've tried to use cordova plugin inappbrowser without any success. I'm debugging in Weinre, so if it doesn't work, I'm not getting any error messages. I just need to link to the image when a user clicks on the preview image in the popup. Here is my script:

```
function gpChartResultAvailable(results, messages) {
    domAttr.set(dom.byId("chartLink"), "innerHTML", "Three Week Chart");
    //clear any existing features displayed in the popup 
    map.infoWindow.clearFeatures();

    var content = "";
    if (results == 0) {
        var chartPath = "http://ourserver.com/Test_Charts/Three_Week_Chart_for_" + locationStr + ".png";
        content = '<IMG SRC="' + chartPath + '" width=100% height=100%/><br/><br/>';

    } else {
        content = " Unable To Generate Chart";
    }

    map.infoWindow.resize(225, 145);
    map.infoWindow.reposition();
    map.infoWindow.setContent(content);
    map.infoWindow.setTitle(locationStr);
};
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. var chartPath = "http://ourserver.com/Test_Charts/Three_Week_Chart_for_" + locationStr + ".png";
       content = '<IMG SRC="' + chartPath + '" width=100% height=100% onclick="window.open(this.src)"/><br/>';

Comment: Also this: var chartPath = "http://ourserver.com/Test_Charts/Three_Week_Chart_for_" + locationStr + ".png";
       content = '<IMG SRC="' + chartPath + '" width=100% height=100% onclick="window.navigator.app.loadUrl("' + chartPath + '", { openExternal:true });"/>';